# Falla en Actualizar botón de opción en BBDD [R - Shiny ]

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Estoy realizando **PFC** y hay un error que no logro solucionar.
Estoy intentando mostrar una tabla que tiene botones de opciones que pueden variar: *positivo, negativo y neutro*, cuando el usuario desee cambiarlo.
Se supone que al ser modificado debe *actualizarse* la **BBDD.**
La tabla varia según el método que escoja el usuario.

El problema es que el usuario escoge un método aparece la tabla que actualiza la **BBDD** al cambiar el botón de opción el usuario, pero cuando el usuario escoge otro método (u otra fecha, vamos al realizar algun cambio en la seleccion de datos de entrada) y vuelve a realizar lo mismo ya no funciona, lo mismo ocurre si vuelve a escoger el método que funcionaba.

Podría alguien echarme una mano, estoy desesperada y he de presentarlo.
 Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les anexo mi *código*:

```
**** ui.R
 tabPanel("Trend Analysis", value = "tab11",
       br(),
       sidebarLayout(
        # Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
        sidebarPanel(
          br(), br(), br(),
          selectInput("clave_busqueda", "Completed searches:",
                      choices = sql_palabras_busqueda("en"), selected = "text"),
          hr(),
          br(),
          selectInput("metodo_elegido", "Methods:",
                      sql_metodo("en")),
          hr(),
          br(),
          # Rango de fecha
          dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                         label = 'Date range input: ',
                         start = Sys.Date() - 2, end = Sys.Date(),
                         max = Sys.Date(), min = '2017-05-01'
          ),
          hr(),
          br()
          #change the color of action button
          # actionButton("update_hist", "Run Historical", icon("paper-plane"),
          #               style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4")
        ),
        mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabhistorical",
           # Muestra la trayectoria de la polaridad de los tweets en una fecha determinada y para un metodo elegido
           # Total de positivos, negativos o neutros en cada fecha (porcentajes)
           tabPanel("Trajectory", value = "tab12",
               br(),
               h3(textOutput("title_historico")),
               br(),
               # Horizontal Bar Plot
               plotOutput("view_historico_syuzhet"),
               br(),hr(),br(),br(),
               dataTableOutput("view_hist_syuzhet"),
               br(),hr(),br(),br(),
               dataTableOutput("view_hist_syuzhet_perc"),
               br(),br()
           ),
           # Muestra la polaridad de los tweets en una fecha determinada y un metodo elegido
           tabPanel("Historical", value = "tab17",
              br(),
              h3(textOutput("title_historico_tweets")),
              br(),
              # Tabla con los tweets
              DT::dataTableOutput("view_hist_tweets"),
              br(),br(),
              verbatimTextOutput('sel'),
              br(),br()
           )
         ) # tabsetPanel - historical

       ) # mainPanel
      ) #sidebarLayout
   ) #tabPanel - Historical



***** Server.R

analyze_historical_tweets <- reactive({
  # Change when the "update" button is pressed...
  input$metodo_elegido
  input$clave_busqueda
  input$dateRange
  input$text
  # ...but not for anything else
  isolate({
      sql_historico_tweets(input$clave_busqueda, input$dateRange[1], input$dateRange[2],
                           input$idioma, input$metodo_elegido)
  })
})

# titulo historico
output$title_historico_tweets<- renderText({
  paste("Historical for ", input$clave_busqueda, "by Method: ", input$metodo_elegido)
})

# Tabla con los tweets y su sentimiento. Opcion a cambiar el sentimiento
# https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/
output$view_hist_tweets <- DT::renderDataTable(
  # escape = FALSE para renderizar contenido HTML arbitrario en la tabla: los radio buttons
  # Tabla de la matriz con los radio buttons creados para cada tweet
  matriz_radio(analyze_historical_tweets(), input),
  escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE, 
  options  = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
  callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                var $this = $(this.node());
                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
                });
                Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")

  # The JavaScript callback is to make sure all rows have their ID's
  # and the class shiny-input-radiogroup, so that Shiny can recognize 
  # these radio buttons after Shiny.bindAll()
)

output$sel = renderPrint({
  valor_original = analyze_historical_tweets()         # Devuelve: id, tweet y sentimiento del tweet
  id_tw = as.character(analyze_historical_tweets()$id)              # id del tweet que tiene boton de opcion original

  valor_boton = sapply(id_tw, function(i) input[[i]])  # Valor del sentimiento que toma el boton de opcion al cambiarlo el usuario

print("1092 jjj")
print(input$metodo_elegido)
print(valor_original$sentimiento)
print(sapply(id_tw, function(i) input[[i]]) )

  # Actualizar sentimientos de los tweet si el usuario lo cambia a traves del boton de opcion
  actualizar_sentimiento(analyze_historical_tweets(), valor_original, valor_boton, input$metodo_elegido)
 })


**** global.R
sql_historico_tweets <- function(input_clave_busqueda, input_start, input_end, input_idioma, input_metodo){
    # Buscar id del metodo
    sql_id_metodo = paste0("select id_metodo from t_metodos where metodo like '", input_metodo, "'")
    query_id_metodo = sendDataSql(sql_id_metodo)
    d_id_metodo   = fetch(query_id_metodo, n = -1)  # Funcion de busqueda: fetch

    # Selecciona el id de la palabra de entrada por el usuario para la busqueda
    sql_id_input = paste0("select id_input from t_input_text 
                          where text like '", input_clave_busqueda, "' and idioma LIKE '", input_idioma, "'")
    query_id_input = sendDataSql(sql_id_input)
    d_id_input   = fetch(query_id_input, n = -1)  # Funcion de busqueda: fetch

    # Diferencia en dias entre las fechas
    # date_strings = c(input_start, input_end)
    # datetimes = strptime(date_strings, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
    # diff_in_days = difftime(datetimes[2], datetimes[1], units = "days") + 1    # Numero de dias seleccionado por usuario
    diff_in_days = dias_seleccionados(input_start, input_end)

    # Selecciono los tweets
    sql_tweet_hist = paste0("SELECT id_tw, tweet, sentimiento from t_tweets, t_sentimientos
                            where id_text_relacion = ", d_id_input, " and cast(fecha_consulta AS DATE) between '", input_start, 
                            "' and '", input_end, "' and idioma like '", input_idioma, "' and metodo_ide = ", d_id_metodo,
                            " and id_tw = tweet_id")
    # Cast me toma solo la fecha sin la hora, ya que convierte en date
    query_id_input = sendDataSql(sql_tweet_hist)
    d_tweet_hist   = fetch(query_id_input, n = -1)  # Funcion de busqueda: fetch

    clean_text1(d_tweet_hist)

  # print("1276")
  # print(d_id_metodo)

    tweets_seleccionados = c(d_tweet_hist)

  print("1285")
  print(tweets_seleccionados$sentimiento)

    return (tweets_seleccionados)
  }


  # Creo los radio buttons en la matriz para cada tweet
  matriz_radio <- function(tweets_seleccionados, input){
    id = as.character(tweets_seleccionados$id_tw)   # Id como caracter

    # Numero de tweets
    num_tweet = length(tweets_seleccionados$id_tw) 

    tw  = tweets_seleccionados$tweet
    tw1 = iconv(tw, "UTF-8", "latin1", sub="")    # Para eliminar emoticones

    # Matriz con tweets y sentimientos 
    m = matrix(
      as.character(1:4), nrow = num_tweet, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(id, c("Tweet", "Positive", "Negative", "Neutral")) 
    )

    # Extraigo los sentimientos de cada tweet
    sentimiento = tweets_seleccionados$sentimiento

    # Coloco en la matriz los radio buttons
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
      if (sentimiento[i] == 1){
        m[i, 1] = tw1[i]    # Muestra el tweet
        m[i, 2] = sprintf(
          '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" checked>',
          id[i], m[i, 2]
        )
        m[i, 3] = sprintf(
          '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s">',
          id[i], m[i, 3]
        )
        m[i, 4] = sprintf(
          '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s">',
          id[i], m[i, 4]
        ) #id[i]
      }
      else if (sentimiento[i] == -1){
        m[i, 1] = tw1[i]    # Muestra el tweet
        m[i, 3] = sprintf(
          '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" checked>',
          id[i], m[i, 3]
        )
        m[i, 2] = sprintf(
          '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s">',
          id[i], m[i, 2]
        )
        m[i, 4] = sprintf(
          '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s">',
          id[i], m[i, 4]
        )
      }
      else if (sentimiento[i] == 0){
        m[i, 1] = tw1[i]    # Muestra el tweet
        m[i, 4] = sprintf(
          '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" checked>',
          id[i], m[i, 4]
        )
        m[i, 2] = sprintf(
          '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s">',
          id[i], m[i, 2]
        )
        m[i, 3] = sprintf(
          '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s">',
          id[i], m[i, 3]
        )
      }
    }

     #print("MATRIZ")
     #print(m[1:5, 2:4])
        # Ejemplo de salida
        # Positive                                         
        # I need an exercise ..."<input type=\"radio\" name=\"1\" value=\"1\"/>" 
        # Negative                                          
        # I need an exercise ..."<input type=\"radio\" name=\"1\" value=\"-1\"/>"
        # Neutral                                          
        # I need an exercise ..."<input type=\"radio\" name=\"1\" value=\"0\"/>" 

    return(m)
  }


  # Actualizar sentimientos de los tweet si el usuario lo cambia a traves del boton de opcion
  actualizar_sentimiento <- function(d_analyze_historical_tweets, valor_original, valor_boton, name_method){
    # Normalizo valor del boton opción a -1, 0, 1 (negativo, neutro o positivo)
    num_tweet = length(valor_original$id_tw)  # Numero de tweets
    norm_valor_boton = c()                    # Valor del sentimiento del boton normalizado para guardar en BD
    for(i in 1:num_tweet){
      # Positivo
      if (valor_boton[i] == as.character(2)){
        norm_valor_boton = c(norm_valor_boton, 1)  # Valor para actualizar BBDD
      } 
      # Negativo
      else if (valor_boton[i] == as.character(3)){
        norm_valor_boton = c(norm_valor_boton, -1)
      }
      # Neutro
      else if (valor_boton[i] == as.character(4)){
        norm_valor_boton = c(norm_valor_boton, 0)
      }
    }

    # Busco el id del metodo
    sql_id = paste0("select id_metodo from t_metodos where metodo like '", name_method, "'") 
    query_id_input = sendDataSql(sql_id)
    d_id_metodo   = fetch(query_id_input, n = -1)  # Funcion de busqueda: fetch

    # Compruebo si el usuario ha cambiado el valor del sentimiento para actualizar
    for(i in 1:num_tweet){
  print("1402")
  print(valor_original$sentimiento[i])
  print(norm_valor_boton[i]) 
     # if(valor_original$sentimiento[i] != norm_valor_boton[i]){
        # Actualizo el sentimiento en la BBDD  mediante sentencia SQL para la tabla sentimientos    
       sql_sentimientos_act <- paste0("UPDATE t_sentimientos
                                       SET sentimiento = ", norm_valor_boton[i],
                                       " WHERE tweet_id = ", d_analyze_historical_tweets$id[i],
                                       " AND metodo_ide = ", d_id_metodo)
       query_tweets <- sendDataSql(sql_sentimientos_act)
     # }
    }
  }
```

Comment: El código de `ui.R` esta incompleto, sería bueno que lo agregues para poder hacer un dignóstico. Saludos

Comment: Ya he completado el código de ui.R.

Comment: @Akela_sil me encantaría ayudarte... pero el código es... mucho y se conecta a una base de datos (de la que sería bueno conocer el esquema). Podrías incluir un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? (hacé click en el link para ver cómo crearlo y por qué es importante) así lo puedo reproducir local. Gracias!

Comment: @g3rv4,  alguna forma de poder enviaros los ficheros con un pequeño ejemplo y la base de datos?

Comment: @Patricio Moracho , alguna forma de poder enviaros los ficheros con un pequeño ejemplo y la base de datos?

Comment: Tal vez puedas subir el proyecto a un repositorio de github, de hecho te lo recomiendo por seguridad, o compartirlo por google drive o algún servicio similar.

Comment: @Akela_sil lo mejor es que crees un ejemplo donde reproduzcas lo que está fallando. Idealmente, sin conexión a la base de datos (creando los dataframes a mano). Si es con conexión, entonces podés agregar el código para crear las tablas y agregar datos... pensá que cuanto más complejo sea, menos probable es que otra persona te responda, entonces tenés que intentar hacer el ejemplo más sencillo donde se pueda reproducir el problema. Pensá que la idea es que tu pregunta ayude a alguien más :)

Comment: Si has copiado el código completo de `Server.R` lo que veo es que te falta definir la función `server <- function(input, output)` que mapea los datos de entrada con la salida con cada interación en la interfaz.